# Show age check form to users, not bots - SEO safe?

Tags: php, seo, googlebot

I've got an issue where I have an age verification script on my site which prevents pages on the site being indexed by google. The workarounds for this seem pretty flimsy, javascript and css overlays the most common solutions - is there any reason why you couldn't just use PHP to detect if it's a bot accessing the site and if not, show the age check form, if it is, allow through? I'm just wondering if this is seen as bad practice...?

Comment: Google indexer is in fact a bot.

Comment: Serving different content to bots and "normal" visitors can get you banned / penalized in search engines.

Comment: First of all , once you are required to check any user detial such as age, password, id or whatever - there's no way to escape it , whether you're a user or a bot . Once data is not acessible for user it won't be accessible for bots either.

Comment: ok thanks, so serving different content isn't an option then - just wanted to check that. Some sort of modal overlay form is probably my best bet then. Bummer :(

Comment: I don't know why you need to hide something from bots and show something to a user. 
and we don't know google only uses "googlebot" or its variations. May be a regular visitor from Firefox is Google bot ? who knows ?

Comment: @AyeshK because the age verification script stops search engine bots from being able to access other pages on the site, which means only the age check page gets indexed. not great for seo

Comment: Sorry i have no solution for you then... Sounds like some kind of splash page. https://www.google.com/search?q=seo+and+splash+pages

Answer (score 1):

This will work for the Google Bot only, you will need to edit for others:

```
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot"))
{
    // no age check
} else {
    //age check
}
```